# Swift typecasting/pattern-match condition this or that

Tags: swift, reswift

My use case involves a switch statement and trying to build a case that depends on multiple typecasts. This will really help me introduce some composable/clean/less code. The generic multiple conditions won't work as I'm using `let` with the casting and it cant be mutated. Also, fallthrough produces a similar error.

```
case let foo as SomeStruct,
     let foo as SomeOtherStruct:
        // do whatever
```

> Error: Pattern variable bound to type

```
case let foo as SomeStruct:
     fallthrough
case let foo as SomeOtherStruct:
     // do whatever
```

> 'fallthrough' cannot transfer control to a case label that declares variables

Those errors both make sense. Basically, Im asking if there is any way to do a typecasting/pattern-match of `let foo as SomeStruct || SomeOtherStruct`

Edit: for more context, Im doing reducer composition with ReSwift

Comment: What would you expect the static type of `foo` to be?

Comment: a parent struct of both SomeStruct and SomeOtherStruct **edit: implement same protocol* **

Comment: If you find yourself doing a lot of `as` checking, you're probably misusing the type system, and either meant to add a method to a protocol, or meant to use an enum (or possibly meant to use class inheritance). `as` is generally an escape hatch when you have a broken type (like Any). It's generally not something to design with.

Comment: Structs can't have parents. Do you mean classes here?

Comment: No I'm sorry, I mean they both implement the same protocol

Comment: If they have a protocol, why are you adding specialized functionality based on the specific implementor in a switch? Move that functionality to a protocol method implementation for each type. If this leads to code duplication, extract the duplication into a free function or into a separate strategy type (i.e. a type that holds that shared functionality and both structs use).

Comment: On the other hand, if you have a closed list of structs, and you want the logic to be outside the structs (i.e. in a switch statement), that's fine, but then you have an enum, not a struct+protocol. Enums and struct+protocol are duals of each other; you can solve most problems using one or the other and they just have different trade-offs.

Comment: Yea @RobNapier thats what I want

Comment: for more context, im doing reducer composition with ReSwift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about this?

```
struct S1 {
    var a : String
}
struct S2 {
    var a : Int
}
let x = S1(a: "Test")
switch x {
    case let y where (y is S1) || (y is S2): print("S1 or S2")
    default: break
}
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for. Not the cleanest but definitely removes the code in my case.